# Auto click in linux while doing other tasks

Tags: linux, mouse, automation, manjaro

I'm using Manjaro 17.1 with KDE desktop. What I want to do is to click on a position in my desktop automatically, without having to sacrifice the physical mouse so that I can use it in another task.

I know I could use a VM for doing so but it consumes much RAM and CPU.

I used to use Control Click by AutoIt in Windows, but in Linux I don't know how to do that. If I use KDE Activities, the mouse moving and clicking actions affect the other activity environment.

What I want to do is to click on a Flash object in a website, so I know options like Selenium won't work.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What problem are you trying to solve by 'clicking' somewhere? Are you trying to click something (eg a shortcut) on your Desktop itself? I ask as there may be another way of automating what you are trying to do without simulating a 'click' :)

Answer (score 2):

There's a utility called [XdoTool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) that might do what you want. Keep in mind that its activity is quite easy to detect if you're the Flash object or the Web server, so it almost certainly wouldn't work for anything "irregular".

There was a similar tool that was much harder to detect, but it required patching the X distribution and was as pleasant as chewing broken glass (I had to work on that to simulate a user with Parkinson's disease for a usability project).